# TeamCity: how to create custom statistics from a build

Tags: teamcity

I would like to add my own statistics graph to the build. For example, how many tests passed and how many failed.

```
[==========] 85 tests from 16 test suites ran. (1372 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 85 tests.
```

Yes, there is a TeamCity plugin available to interface with google test. But it hasn't been updated for a while and I would like to avoid another plugin.

Is there some syntax that will allow me to add another line to the build script to grep for the number of tests and update some sort of TeamCity variable that can be used to create a custom chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import any test results with help of service messages: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-script-interaction-with-teamcity.html#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ServiceMessages

Basically your build process should produce special stdout which will be parsed by TeamCity and imported into the TeamCity database.

For example, the following lines in stdout will report a single passed test with name 'test1' to TeamCity:
##teamcity[testStarted name='test1']
##teamcity[testFinished name='test1']